# Undefned control sequence problem

Tags: errors

I am typing

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn,leqno,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathds{R}}

\begin{document}

\title{M}
\author{Y}
\date{September 4, 2014}
\maketitle

\textbf{Exercise 1} (Open Balls). Prove \textit{rigorously} that an "open ball" $B_\epsilon(x)$ of radius $\epsilon > 0$ about a point $x$ in $\mathds{R}$ equipped with the Euclidean topology is, in fact, open.

\end{document}
```

And I'm getting the error

> Undefined control sequence problem. ...epsilon>0$ about a point $x$ in $\mathds

What is the problem?

I suspect that I didn't download completely the package `amsmath`. But, I downloaded in my desktop. Is there a problem with this??

Comment: What is `\mathds` supposed to be? Is that perhaps supposed to be `\mathbf`. Or perhaps `\mathbb` which requires the `amssymb`.

Comment: It is the same as \mathbb or \mathbf. I have the same problem when I uses \mathbb or \mathbf

Comment: Instead of trying to download a package at a time, I'd recommend you just download the complete TeXLive2014 and go from there.

Comment: What is TeXLive2014? I'm using MikTex

Comment: @Yk26 You **must** to put `\begin{document}` after `\title, \author, \date` but before `\maketitle`for your document works.

Comment: @Aradnix This is not true: one can have `\title`, `\author` and `\date` either before or after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: But it always gives me an error. That's why I put them in the preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't load the `dsfont` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn,leqno,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathds{R}}

\begin{document}

\title{M}
\author{Y}
\date{September 4, 2014}
\maketitle

\textbf{Exercise 1} (Open Balls). Prove \textit{rigorously} that an "open ball" $B_\epsilon(x)$ of radius $\epsilon > 0$ about a point $x$ in $\mathds{R}$ equipped with the Euclidean topology is, in fact, open. Or will $ x $ live in $ \mathbb R$?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok. My mistake. But the problem is that I also can't use \mathbb{R} Can you explain this too? As I really just want to use amsmath only.

Comment: Load the `amsfonts` package. Bbfonts are not part of basic LaTeX. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another simply solution to your problem. From your own MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%\newcommand{\R}{\mathds{R}} % Anyway it is bad defined

\title{M}
\author{Y}
\date{September 4, 2014}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\paragraph*{Exercise 1} (Open Balls). Prove \emph{rigorously} that an ``open ball'' $B_\epsilon(x)$ of radius $\epsilon > 0$ about a point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Euclidean topology is, in fact, open.

\end{document}
```

Notice that I erased few options of the class because they are redundant since are the default settings. I used `amssymb` instead `amsfonts`, and it is because long ago someone told me to use both is redundant since `amssymb`contains symbols from `amsfonts`. I don't know if that's true, but in this case it works well.

I also chose to change `\texit` and `\textbf` for more suitable options. Not that it is bad in itself, but instead simply highlight the text typographically, you can use `\paragraph*` to give structure and `\emph` what it does is highlight the text regardless of the font you use and that makes it more versatile.

I know that `\paragraph*` is not the best choice, the ideal would have used one of the theorems packages and define a sentence to exercise, but that would complicate the answer too, maybe on a future occasion.